# Heroku Database: Insert operation

Tags: python, postgresql, heroku

I am confused while inserting data to my Postgres Database in heroku.

Here's the thing,

I have created connection to database, then

```
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO users(username, useremail, userpass) VALUES ('"+_name+"','"+_email+"','"+_password+"')")
```

After executing, I checked the sql status by

`print(cursor.statusmessage)`

it returns,

> INSERT 0 1

but on executing, data =

> cursor.fetchall()

it throws me error

> File "/Users/abc/PycharmProjects/testSkillNetwork/app.py",
>   line 75, in signUp
>       data = cursor.fetchall().
>
> ```
> ProgrammingError: no results to fetch
> ```

So, i am unable to understand why 'no results' when insertion is successful.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to issue a `SELECT` query in order to retrieve data from the database.

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM users")
cursor.fetchall()
```

This should give you some results.

Also, you should commit the transaction once you have finished inserting data, otherwise it will be lost. Use:

```
conn.commit()
```

Another, bigger, issue is that the way that you construct your queries is vulnerable to SQL injection. Rather than using string concatenation you should use parameterised queries:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO users(username, useremail, userpass) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)", (_name,_email,_password))
```

With this style the database adapter will substitute the place holders (`%s`) with the values from the tuple of arguments passed to `cursor.execute()`. Not only is this safer, it's a lot easier to read and maintain.

Comment: conn.commit() worked and inserted values in database, actually i had this line but after fetchall(), that's why it was not running. and thanks for the tip. First time i am doing such project, shifting from Android Development...

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what driver are you using to connect to the database, assuming you're using `psycopg2`, which is one of the most famous, what you're observing is a normal behaviour. Reading from [here](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.fetchall):

> ```
> A ProgrammingError is raised if the previous call to execute*() did not produce any result set or no call was issued yet.
> ```

An insert statement produces no result, other that an error in case of failure. If you want to obtain the rows that you've just inserted, query the database again:

```
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM users;")
cur.fetchall()
```

and this will give you the rows.

Aside from this, if you read the [basic usage](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#query-parameters) and the section of parametrized queries, **never** use python string concatenation when executing your queries, because it makes it vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).